# SSRS report fail on Oraclev19 Function call

Tags: oracle, ssrs-2012, oracle19c

Thanks for your time on this question.
I'm new to SSRS but comfortable with basic Oracle SQL's.
I have some ssrs reports that run well on oracle v12 and now have to migrate db to oracle v19.
these reports have several oracle function that are used as dataset source. so on ssrs dataset, under 'query type' i select 'stored procedure' and enter function name with parameters and output. this approach was working well on old set up but in the new setup, it fails with oracle error:

> An error has occured during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Query execution failed for dataset 'region'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
> ORA-06550: line1, column 7: PLS-00221: '<>' is not a procedure or is undefined ORA-06550:line1, column7: PL/SQL: statement ignored.

Some details:
the old versions: Oracle db v12, ssrs report builder v12, oracle client (TBC)
the new version: Oracle db v19, ssrs report builder v15, oracle client OLEDB

when i provide source as SQL query, the dataset works fine.

Could someone pls help on how to get over this error?
Have you called Oracle function from SSRS report?
Most of these function return 'refcursor', could this be an issue?

this has been nagging me for days. Many thanks in advance for your time and effort.

EDIT: I tried dataset source to a simple function GET_FUNC_TEST but that also fails with same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was Oracle driver. OLEDB driver doesnt support refcursors. Once we installed oracle / odbc client, it was working smoothly.